# Selectpicker on dynamically created select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

i'm using bootstrap-select in a form with several selects, but i clone or create new selects with new ids and same class and use:

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker("render"); or
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
```

and the new selects doesn't get updated, i also try cloning both normal select and created bootstrap-select change ids and data-id and `$(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");` but this doesn't work.

How can this be done.

**UPDATE**

This is the basic HTML, basically i'm using Django formset, here i have a form with a table, each row is a new form instance with inputs and selects.

```
<tr class="dynamic-form">
 <td class="" style="text-align: center">
  <input type="number" name="caracteristicas-0-ORDER" value="1" id="id_caracteristicas-0-ORDER">
 </td>
 <td class="" style="text-align: center">
  <select name="caracteristicas-0-caract" data-live-search="true" class="form-control selectpicker" id="id_caracteristicas-0-caract" style="display: none;">
  <option value="1" selected="">Nombre</option>
  <option value="2">Ref</option>
  <option value="3">Modelo</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

The Javascript is basically this:

```
---- onClickButton ----
row = tr.clone(true); <----- this was the problem
/* clear values, change id's, etc. */
row.insertBefore(lastRow).show();
row.find('.bootstrap-select').remove();
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker("render");
```

Comment: Can you put the relevant JavaScript and HTML into your question?

Comment: You probably need to call `$(".selectpicker").selectpicker()` after adding the new raw html select boxes to initialize the plugin on those new elements.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The selector works and finds new html selects, but they don't get updated by bootstrap-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all library code, the problem was in this line:

```
row = tr.clone(true);
```

When you use `clone(true)` you get a copy of the element AND all events handlers etc. You need to get a clean copy of the element structure only.

So the solution is:

```
row = tr.clone();
```